# How to give hover effect to next div using css

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to give hover effect to specific div, but that div is not a child of that div, which I hover

I have code, so, you can understand

```js
$(".pannel-icon").click(function(){
    $(".opening-menu").toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
body{overflow:hidden}
a{cursor:pointer}
.opening-menu{float:right;position:absolute;right:-100px; top: 50px;transition:0.2s all linear}
.main-menu{float:right}
.show{right:0;transition:0.2s all linear}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-menu">
  <span>coins:$100</span>
  <a class="pannel-icon">
    <span class="pannel-menu-hover">Menu</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="opening-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>menu1</li>
    <li>menu1</li>
    <li>menu1</li>
    <li>menu1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Inside this code, I want to hover `.opening-menu` when I hover `.pannel-icon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it your answer?

```js
$(".pannel-icon, .opening-menu").hover(function(){
    $(".opening-menu").toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
body{overflow:hidden}
a{cursor:pointer}
.opening-menu{float:right;position:absolute;right:-100px; top: 10px;transition:0.2s all linear}
.main-menu{float:right}
.show{right:0;transition:0.2s all linear}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-menu">
  <span>coins:$100</span>
  <a class="pannel-icon">
    <span class="pannel-menu-hover">Menu</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="opening-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>menu1</li>
    <li>menu1</li>
    <li>menu1</li>
    <li>menu1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But if you try and click a menu item, the menu disappears? It disappears as soon as you don't hover over the Menu text?

Comment: @david i updated it. your right brother it should stay at that place becuase this menu should click.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you're saying, check this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nhnb9a5g/1/. If you hover over Menu, the menu appears but then disappears as soon as you try and click an item?

If so, check this revised fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zm93hL3e/3/

Add the following jQuery:

```
$(".pannel-icon, .opening-menu").hover(function(){
    $(".opening-menu").toggleClass('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jquery hover function or selector to achieve this. But I prefer to place the opening-menu within the link. That way it's always hovered when you are hovering an item in the menu.

Comment: This should be a comment. Anyway, thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand correctly your question, do you want to change CSS properties in the class called `opening-menu`, right?

So, you can add in your CSS:

```
.opening-menu:hover{float:right;position:absolute;right:-100px; top: 50px;transition:0.2s all linear}
```

The complete CSS code will be:

```
body{overflow:hidden}
a{cursor:pointer}
.opening-menu:hover{float:right;position:absolute;right:-100px; top: 50px;transition:0.2s all linear}
.main-menu{float:right}
.show:hover{right:0;transition:0.2s all linear}
```

Alternatively, you can use a javascript function like this:

```
    $(".pannel-icon").hover(hoverDiv);

    function hoverDiv(){
    $(".opening-menu").css({
    'float':'right';
    'position':'absolute';
    'right':'-100px'; 
    'top': '50px';
    'transition':'0.2s'}) 
}
```